# Unique clustered index vs primary key

Tags: sybase, composite-primary-key, clustered-index

I have a table with composite primary key of 7 fields, but table is allowing duplicate entries with primary key. Later I noticed it also has Unique clustered index with 10 fields including 7 of primary key. Is that the reason system allowing to insert duplicate primary key data?

If so, I am not able to think of reason creating Unique Index with field additional fields not much in use for searching data except limit of fields in composite key. I tried to look for answer but didn't find result for limitation. Can someone please help. I am using sybase.

Comment: by definition `primary key` implies `unique` so I don't understand how you can have a `primary key` that also allows duplicates; please update the question with the Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version; also provide the `composite primary key` (w/ duplicate attribute?) and `unique clusted index` definitions

Answer (score 0):

Peformance-wise, clustered key, set correctly (aka does not include all fields you deem unique), gives you the most advantage.
7-column PK is a strange construct; if you need to guard uniqueness, I would go for a combination of a cluster + unique constraint.